# Htaccess 301 redirect url not working as per expectation

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to match url in htaccess and want 301 redirect based on the url check. But its not working properly as per my expectations.

Here is what I want to achieve and here is my code try.

MY OLD URL - https://www.mywebsite.com/support-detail/1903/my-title

MY NEW URL TO REDIRECT 301 - https://www.mywebsite.com/support-detail/my-title

**.htaccess**

```
RedirectMatch 301 /support-detail/$1/$2 /support-detail/$2
```

As you can see my code, I want all the pages which has something like this, `/support-detail/$1/$2` , I want theme to redirect at `/support-detail/$2` but its keep saying 404 page not found .. I even try with `/support-detail/$1` but its still not working ..

Can someone guide me what I am doing wrong here in my url.

Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.
Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^(support-detail)/\d+/([\w-]+)/?$  /$1/$2 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave, oh ok sure I have edited my solution now let me know if this helps you, cheers

Comment: `(how-can-employees-clock-inout-of-time-clock)` this can not be static ..

Comment: `(how-can-employees-clock-inout-of-time-clock)` this can be anything but string only ..

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave, ok sure I have edited solution now let me know how it goes

Comment: I am trying this url `http://localhost/rosterelf/support-detail/1451/how-can-i-set-up-rosterelf-time-clock` but it doesnt redirect to `http://localhost/rosterelf/support-detail/how-can-i-set-up-rosterelf-time-clock`

Comment: it should only remove the id `1451` from the url and keep same dynamic title and redirect

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave, Please try my edited one now and let me know then, thank you.

Comment: ok .. Let me try and update you whether its working or not.

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave, so it means you have other rules in your htacces file too?

Comment: I dont have other rules .. i have only this rule .. putting this code only gives me internal server error .. https://paste.ee/p/iPjSw this is my htacces looks like .. i putting your code below `RewriteRule ^robots.txt - [L]`

Comment: I have removed all code and put only this code https://paste.ee/p/oDTDl still gives me internal server error .. so that means there is something wrong in this code `RewriteRule ^(support-detail)/\d+/([\w-]+)/?$ /?$ $1/$2 [R=301,NC,L]`

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave, ok I have edited the rules now, could you please try my edited ones and let me know how it goes then, thank you.

Comment: If i do this `localhost/rosterelf/support-detail/124/how-can-i-set-up-rosterelf-time-clock` its redirecting me to `http://localhost/var/www/html/rosterelf/support-detail/how-can-i-set-up-rosterelf-time-clock`

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave, ok try this rule once `RewriteRule ^(support-detail)/\d+/([\w-]+)/?$  /$1/$2 [R=301,NC,L]` and let me know how it goes?

Comment: ok almost working now .. if i do this `localhost/rosterelf/support-detail/124/how-can-i-set-up-rosterelf-time-clock` its redirecting me to `http://localhost/support-detail/how-can-i-set-up-rosterelf-time-clock` notice .. its not adding `rosterelf` in the url ..

Comment: MY live site doesnt have suburl .. so i think it can work on live website .. but my question is .. is it possible to make it work on both local and live server ?

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave, `its not adding rosterelf in the url ` Sorry I didn't get on this one, could you please elaborate more on this one?

Comment: http://localhost/rosterelf/ this is my local server url .. and this is my live site url https://www.rosterelf.com/ .. so when i do this `localhost/rosterelf/support-detail/123/how-do-i-process-a-payroll-to-myob` its redirecting me to `http://localhost/support-detail/how-do-i-process-a-payroll-to-myob` so if you see url /... it doesnt add `rosterelf` and hence page not found error ... but i believe on live site it will work .. because in local server .. its not has virtual host .. so my question is, is it possible to make it work on both live and local ?

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave, oh ok got it, you mean from local to `rosterelf` domain you want it to redirect, then you need to make entry in virtualhost part in config file, you could configure it I believe, or may be you can play around to make localhost as your host `rosterelf`?(not sure on this one), let me know if you are able to make it, cheers.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(support-detail)/\d+/([\w-]+)/?$  /$1/$2 [R=301,NC,L]` this code works for me .. plz update your code in answer and i will set as correct answer and upvote..Thank you so much

Comment: its fine now .. i dont mind not working in local server as far as its working on live server :) Thank you so much ..

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave, Your welcome buddy, I have updated the answer now, cheers and happy learning on this great forum :)

Comment: Absolutely .. This forum has some great people like you who are always ready to help .. Thank you so much for all these ..

Comment: Hello are you round ? @RavinderSingh13 ?

Comment: Above changes works for my support details pages .. but I want this url https://www.rosterelf.com/blog-detail/2211/how-to-create-a-winning-team to be redirected to https://www.rosterelf.com/blog/how-to-create-a-winning-team .. and I am trying to put this condition `RewriteRule ^(blog-detail)/\d+/([\w-]+)/?$  /blog/$1/$2 [R=301,NC,L]` but its not working

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave, Hello sir, Good to see you again, I would like to request you if you could open a new question on this one and give me the link to discuss on this one, let us not confuse future users here :) since this thread is closed, cheers :) Let me know.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66794249/htaccess-301-blog-redirect-url can you please see this question and help me .. Thanks

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave, sure, let me check now.

Comment: I have one more .htaccess rule needs to add .. can you help me here please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66801455/htaccess-redirect-from-old-url-to-new-url .. Thanks