# Htaccess 301 blog redirect url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have done 301 redirects on my live site something like from this url `https://www.rosterelf.com/support-detail/1424/how-can-i-copy-shifts-from-a-day-to-another` to this url `https://www.rosterelf.com/support-detail/how-can-i-copy-shifts-from-a-day-to-another` and its working fine as per my expectations. Here is my .htaccess code how I made it work.

```
RewriteRule ^(support-detail)/\d+/([\w-]+)/?$  /$1/$2 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Now I want to add one more condition for my blog which I want to redirect.

Say for example , I have this url `https://www.rosterelf.com/blog-detail/2211/how-to-create-a-winning-team` which I want to redirect to `https://www.rosterelf.com/blog/how-to-create-a-winning-team` and hence I put below code but unfortunately its not working for me.

```
RewriteRule ^(blog-detail)/\d+/([\w-]+)/?$  /blog/$1/$2 [R=301,NC,L]
```

This is how my .htaccess file looks like.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    ##
    ## You may need to uncomment the following line for some hosting environments,
    ## if you have installed to a subdirectory, enter the name here also.
    ##
    # RewriteBase /

    ##
    ## Uncomment following lines to force HTTPS.
    ##
    # RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    # RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,R=301]

    ##
    ## Allow robots.txt
    ##
    RewriteRule ^robots.txt - [L]

    ## 301 redirect for old support details page url to new one 
    ## OLD URL https://www.rosterelf.com/support-detail/1903/how-can-employees-clock-inout-of-time-clock-different-slug 
    ## NEW URL https://www.rosterelf.com/support-detail/how-can-employees-clock-inout-of-time-clock-different-slug 
    
    RewriteRule ^(support-detail)/\d+/([\w-]+)/?$  /$1/$2 [R=301,NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^blog-detail/\d+/([\w-]+)/?$ /blog/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

    ##
    ## Black listed folders
    ##
    RewriteRule ^bootstrap/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^config/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^vendor/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/cms/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/logs/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/framework/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/temp/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/app/uploads/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]

    ##
    ## White listed folders
    ##
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/.well-known/*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/uploads/public/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/media/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/resized/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/temp/public/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/themes/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/plugins/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/modules/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
    RewriteRule !^index.php index.php [L,NC]

    ##
    ## Block all PHP files, except index
    ##
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
    RewriteRule !^index.php index.php [L,NC]

    ##
    ## Standard routes
    ##
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Can someone guide me how can I resolve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please confirm if these are the only 2 Rules in your htaccess file? Or you have other rules too? Just want to make sure we have all the rules shown here  else it may effect other things, thank you.

Comment: Well I have only these 2 rules // here is my .htaccess file looks like https://paste.ee/p/aEd8R

Comment: Could you please post them in your question, sorry link is not opening for me and its encouraged to post all details into question itself, thank you.

Comment: what should I post ? an entire htaccess file code ?

Comment: yeah, for better understanding of question into your question please.

Comment: ok let me put entire code ..

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 it seems like anubhava's solution worked for me .. I thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have 2 separate redirect rules like this:

```sh
RewriteRule ^(support-detail)/\d+/([\w-]+)/?$ /$1/$2 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^blog-detail/\d+/([\w-]+)/?$ /blog/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Make sure you completely clear your browser cache and keep these rules at top of your .htaccess

btw you can combine multiple `Black listed folders` rules into one:

```
##
## Black listed folders
##
RewriteRule ^(?:bootstrap|config|vendor|storage/(?:cms|logs|framework|temp/protected|app/uploads/protected))/ index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Your solution worked for me .. Thank you so much to you.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Added few more fixes to your htaccess file along with new rules.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

##
## You may need to uncomment the following line for some hosting environments,
## if you have installed to a subdirectory, enter the name here also.
##
# RewriteBase /

##
## Uncomment following lines to force HTTPS.
##
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

##
## Allow robots.txt
##
RewriteRule ^robots.txt - [NC,L]

## 301 redirect for old support details page url to new one 
## OLD URL https://www.rosterelf.com/support-detail/1903/how-can-employees-clock-inout-of-time-clock-different-slug 
## NEW URL https://www.rosterelf.com/support-detail/how-can-employees-clock-inout-of-time-clock-different-slug 

RewriteRule ^(support-detail)/\d+/([\w-]+)/?$  /$1/$2 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^blog-detail/\d+/([\w-]+)/?$ /blog/$1 [R=301,NC,L]


##
## Black listed folders
##
RewriteRule ^(?:bootstrap|config|vendor|storage/(?:cms|logs|framework|temp/protected|app/uploads/protected))/ index.php [L,NC]


##
## White listed folders
##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/.well-known/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/uploads/public/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/media/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/resized/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/temp/public/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/themes/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/plugins/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/modules/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
RewriteRule !^index\.php index.php [L,NC]

##
## Block all PHP files, except index
##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
RewriteRule !^index\.php index.php [L,NC]

##
## Standard routes
##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```