# htaccess redirect from old url to new url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I am trying to redirect from old url to new url in htaccess and here is my code/try/attempts without any luck.

OLD URL - https://www.rosterelf.com/blog/why-i-always-hire-for-attitude-over-skill-usually

NEW URL - https://www.rosterelf.com/blog/why-i-always-hire-attitude-over-skill-usually

`.htaccess` code try 1

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/why-i-always-hire-for-attitude-over-skill-usually /blog/why-i-always-hire-attitude-over-skill-usually`

I have couple of other 301 redirects but even if I comment those, above condition does not work so believe others conditions are not in fault.

Here is my full `htaccess` code how it looks like.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    ##
    ## You may need to uncomment the following line for some hosting environments,
    ## if you have installed to a subdirectory, enter the name here also.
    ##
    # RewriteBase /

    ##
    ## Uncomment following lines to force HTTPS.
    ##
    # RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    # RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,R=301]

    ##
    ## Allow robots.txt
    ##
    RewriteRule ^robots.txt - [L]

    ## 301 redirect for old support details page url to new one 
    ## OLD URL https://www.rosterelf.com/support-detail/1903/how-can-employees-clock-inout-of-time-clock-different-slug 
    ## NEW URL https://www.rosterelf.com/support-detail/how-can-employees-clock-inout-of-time-clock-different-slug 
    
    RewriteRule ^(support-detail)/\d+/([\w-]+)/?$  /$1/$2 [R=301,NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^blog-detail/\d+/([\w-]+)/?$ /blog/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/why-i-always-hire-for-attitude-over-skill-usually /blog/why-i-always-hire-attitude-over-skill-usually

    ##
    ## Black listed folders
    ##
    RewriteRule ^bootstrap/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^config/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^vendor/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/cms/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/logs/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/framework/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/temp/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/app/uploads/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]

    ##
    ## White listed folders
    ##
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/.well-known/*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/uploads/public/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/media/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/resized/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/temp/public/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/themes/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/plugins/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/modules/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
    RewriteRule !^index.php index.php [L,NC]

    ##
    ## Block all PHP files, except index
    ##
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
    RewriteRule !^index.php index.php [L,NC]

    ##
    ## Standard routes
    ##
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Can someone guide me what should I do to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine ON
##
## You may need to uncomment the following line for some hosting environments,
## if you have installed to a subdirectory, enter the name here also.
##
# RewriteBase /

##
## Uncomment following lines to force HTTPS.
##
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,R=301]

##
## Allow robots.txt
##
RewriteRule ^robots.txt - [NC,L]

## 301 redirect for old support details page url to new one 
## OLD URL https://www.rosterelf.com/support-detail/1903/how-can-employees-clock-inout-of-time-clock-different-slug 
## NEW URL https://www.rosterelf.com/support-detail/how-can-employees-clock-inout-of-time-clock-different-slug 

RewriteRule ^(support-detail)/\d+/([\w-]+)/?$  /$1/$2 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^blog-detail/\d+/([\w-]+)/?$ /blog/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/why-i-always-hire-for-attitude-over-skill-usually /blog/why-i-always-hire-attitude-over-skill-usually [R=301,NC,L]

##
## Black listed folders
##
RewriteRule ^(?:bootstrap|config|vendor|storage/(?:cms|logs|framework|temp/protected|app/uploads/protected))/ index.php [L,NC]


##
## White listed folders
##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/.well-known/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/uploads/public/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/media/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/resized/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/temp/public/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/themes/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/plugins/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/modules/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
RewriteRule !^index\.php index.php [L,NC]

##
## Block all PHP files, except index
##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
RewriteRule !^index\.php index.php [L,NC]

##
## Standard routes
##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave, Your welcome, happy to help cheers :)